# PowerShell to display cluster dashboard

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Using powershell, I would like to display the cluster name, role status, node status and event status...

I currently use the cluster manager to view this information, but I want to automate an hourly email with the cluster information...

[image]

The information I am most interested in resides in the cluster group box.

with particular focus on the 'Event Status' field with a one hour time frame.

So long question short...   what powershell command will present the Event Status per cluster.